# Can not send notification with firebase on another laptop

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I want to send a notification to an android emulator through firebase, but it is not possible to send from another machine. (I mean if I run the emulator on laptop A and run the api on another machine B).

Please can you answer and give me a solution to this problem?

If I run on the same laptop the notification is sent, but if I run on another machine I get:

```
com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: Unknown error while making a remote service
```

Did it miss any information when I init a FirebaseMessaging

```
    @Bean
    FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging() throws IOException {
        GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials
                .fromStream(new ClassPathResource("firebase-service-account.json").getInputStream());
        FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = FirebaseOptions
                .builder()
                .setCredentials(googleCredentials)
                .build();
        FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(firebaseOptions, "my-app");
        return FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(app);
    }
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)